# When send Parameter pagenumber to web api by post man action not working or recognize?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, web-api-testing

I work on .net core 6  web api I face issue when

send paramter pagenumber on url by post man

action not catched by break point debug .

so what is issue and How to solve It ?

i try with url

```
https://localhost:7235/api/items/pageNumber=1

[HttpGet("{pageNumber}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(int pageNumber)
    {
        
    }
```

it return error 200 bad Request .

but i try with url below

```
https://localhost:7235/api/items/
   [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
  
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(int pageNumber)
    {
        
       
    }
```

it working hit controller success and return data success  from`items` controller action `get all` .

so What is issue please and How to solve it ?

**Updated post not working**

```
[HttpGet("{pageNumber}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(int pageNumber)
{
}
for this action you need to use this url:

https://localhost:7235/api/items/1
```

not working and it give me error 500 internal server error

all controller items

```
using DomainModel.Entities;
using DomainModel.Pagination;
using DomainModel.ViewModel;
using k8s.Models;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Service.Contract;
using Service.Features.CustomerFeatures.Commands;
using Service.Features.CustomerFeatures.Queries;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ItemsController : Controller
    {
      
        private readonly IitemService _iitem;
        private readonly IPageHelper<ItemsViewModel> _pageHelper;
        public ItemsController(IitemService iitem, IPageHelper<ItemsViewModel> pageHelper)
        {
            _iitem = iitem;
            _pageHelper = pageHelper;
        }
       
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Items item)
        {
            await _iitem.AddAsync(item);
            return Ok();
           
        }

        [HttpGet("{pageNumber}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(int pageNumber)
        {

            var allitems = _iitem.GetAllItems();

            var result = _pageHelper.GetPage(allitems.AsQueryable(), pageNumber);

            var itemsdata = new ItemsPageViewModel
            {
                items = result.Items,
                Pager = result.Pager
            };

            return Ok(itemsdata);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)
        {
           
            var details = await _iitem.GetByIdAsync(id);

         
            return Ok(details);
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            await _iitem.DeleteAsync(id);
            return Ok();
           
        }
 
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, Items item)
        {
            if (id != item.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            await _iitem.UpdateAsync(id, item);
            return Ok();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are actually getting is

> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.

This is because you have two actions that have the same route:

```cs
// for this action you need to use this url:
// https://localhost:7235/api/items/1

[HttpGet("{pageNumber}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(int pageNumber)
{
    var allitems = _iitem.GetAllItems();

    var result = _pageHelper.GetPage(allitems.AsQueryable(), pageNumber);

    var itemsdata = new ItemsPageViewModel
    {
        items = result.Items,
        Pager = result.Pager
    };

    return Ok(itemsdata);
}

// for this action you ALSO need to use this url:
// https://localhost:7235/api/items/1

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)
{       
    var details = await _iitem.GetByIdAsync(id);
         
    return Ok(details);
}
```

Both actions are `HttpGet` and both use the same route:

`https://localhost:7235/api/items/x`

you need to change the route for one of them.

[Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: thanks for support last link working but first link not working https://localhost:7235/api/items/1 not working so why not working

Comment: ok good but tell me how to change action getitembyid to avoid crash so what i do to change it

Comment: You can change the attribute of `GetAll` to `[HttpGet]` instead of `[HttpGet("{pageNumber}")]` and call like this: `https://localhost:7235/api/items?pageNumber=1`